# PHP function not work properly

Tags: php, function, session, if-statement

I'm creating simple function with if condition to grand access to user:

The following code is working fine.

```php
$_SESSION['role'] = 3

if($_SESSION['role'] == 1 || $_SESSION['role'] == 2){
    echo "Access Granted";
}
else
{
    echo "Access Denied";
}
```

The above code works  for me but not when I convert this into function like code below:

```php
function access($allowed_users) {

    foreach ($allowed_users as $key => $value) {
            $user .= $_SESSION['role'] ." == ".$value." || ";  // Here I'm generating statement to use in If condition
    }

    $user = substr(trim($user), 0, -3);

    if($user){
        echo "Access Granted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
}

access(array('1', '2'));
```

This does not work and always shows `Access Granted` when it should show `Access Denied` because in `$_SESSION['role']` value is 3.

Comment: You cannot just pass the string to `if` and expect it to parse and execute it as the php code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't generate a condition like you do during runtime unless you use `eval`.

```php
foreach ($allowed_users as $key => $value) {
        $user .= $_SESSION['role'] ." == ".$value." || ";  // Here I'm generating statement to use in If condition
}

$user = substr(trim($user), 0, -3);
```

What you need is the function `in_array`:

```php
function access($allowed_users)
{
    // in_array needs always an array as second parameter
    // handle a non array argument: (e.g. access(2))
    if (!is_array($allowed_users)) $allowed_users = array($allowed_users);

    // Check if $_SESSION['role'] is in $allowed_users
    if (in_array($_SESSION['role'], $allowed_users)) {
        echo 'Access granted';
    } else {
        echo 'Access denied';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot evaluate a string like that - your code simply returns true due to php type comparison:

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

You could (but certainly should not) use `if(eval($user))`. A refactor would be better:

```
function access($allowed_users) {

    if(in_array($_SESSION['role'], $allowed_users)) // There was syntax error here because bracket was not closed
    {
        echo "Access Granted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your `$user` var is `0` or `false`, the condition will always evaluate to true and it will execute and echo `Access Granted`. You'll need to come up with a more solid conditional statement that only evaluates to true if access is granted. Hint, check for value `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Note the different

```
S_SESSION['userrole']
```

and

```
$_SESSION['user']
```

in your function and the code above it. Did you change the session var ?